# UI in ReactJS is not up in new on-prem server

Tags: reactjs, content-security-policy

When migrating to a new on-prem server the application using Reactjs is not up in the new server. It works fine in existing development and production server.

Following is the error:

[image]

Please let me know if you need more details.

Tried following solutions by adding meta tags in index.html but none worked

```
<meta http-equiv="content-security-policy"
  content="default-src 'none'; script-src 'self';
  connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self';
  style-src 'self' 'sha256-Xr1dXtyLJov883o4WiQYkueJDTTcgCmG4TiYMNhDs+Q=';" />
  
<meta http-equiv="content-security-policy"
  content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self';
  connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self';
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">

<meta http-equiv="content-security-policy"
           content="default-src 'none'; script-src 'self';
           connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self';
           style-src 'self' 'sha256-Xr1dXtyLJov883o4WiQYkueJDTTcgCmG4TiYMNhDs+Q=';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the response headers for the page. There is a most likely a "Content-Security-Policy" header with the value "default-src 'self'" set on the new server. You are adding other policies, but as all content has to pass all policies, this can only make the total policy stricter. You need to identify where and how the existing policy is set and modify/remove it.

Comment: They have set configurations in the new-server 'Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';"'......it is not possible to edit/modify the server-side configuration...Any code level changes that we can try to avoid this error?Can anyone pls help me here..

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/9239311/halvor-sakshaug : Can you please provide help on this..

Comment: You will need to identify what could set the header, it could be React adding it, or a webserver, proxy etc. I can't help any further than this.